# Adding click listener to an array of JQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my javascript:

```
function scrollTo(position) {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: position
    }, 500);
}

var titles = $('.title');
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    titles[i].click(function() {
        console.log('click');
        scrollTo(0);
    });
}
```

It's supposed to select all three titles and apply a click listener that will scroll the page back to the top. Unfortunately I am not getting the message in the console nor is it scrolling.

Everywhere I have looked online has given for loops exactly like this to apply a click listener to multiple JQuery objects but for some reason it won't work for me. I'm afraid I may have made a stupid mistake but I can't find it.

Comment: You need `$(titles[i]).click(...);` for that to work. Or `titles.eq(i).click(...)`

Comment: `titles[i]` returns a DOM object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code did not work was because of this line

```
titles[i].click(function() {
```

When you access a `jQuery` object with a index, you are technically accessing the `DOM` element and not the `jQuery` object anymore. And the `DOM` object does not have a `click` method. If you would have opened your console, you would have seen an error. If you still want to use a for loop, you will have to convert that to a `jQuery` object first.

```
$(titles[i]).click(function() {
```

If you would have done that, it would work as expected.

Also if you still do not want to double wrap it, you could have also used `.eq` to get the `jQuery` object from the array.

```
titles.eq(i).click(function() {
```

You need not iterate over the jQuery objects to assign event handlers. You could just do it in one line.

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    scrollTo(0);
 });
```

Also check the version of jQuery you are using, if it is the latest then you could use `on`

```
$('.title').on('click', function() {
```

Also you need to make sure that the elements with class `title` are present on the page when you associate the events.

Comment: This worked thank you! Why would the way I did it not work? I've used .click() on single JQuery objects before.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, should give you what your looking for.

```
$('.title').click(function () {
   $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
});
```

also as Sushanth said, if you have a new version of jQuery you can use .on(click)